# Python - py_compile has no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation

I'm trying to check for errors in python code, and I need access to the error log itself (I can't just check to see if the `.pyc` file was created).

My current process is I have a script to run `python3 -m py_compile test.py`, where `test.py` is "aegsedrg" and nothing else (in other words, invalid python code).

When  `python3 test.py` is run, the result is an error (as expected):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    aegsedrg
NameError: name 'aegsedrg' is not defined
```

However, `python3 -m py_compile test.py` returns (through stdout or stderr) no errors.

This is on a Ubuntu 16.04 server, and I have recently upgraded and updated it. I have also completely reinstalled Python 3. I don't think this is a permission issue, `test.py` is 777.

Why does `python3 -m py_compile test.py` return nothing?

-edit-

I have also tried to use the following python script to do this:

```
import py_compile
print("Here")
py_compile.compile("test.py")
print("Here2")
```

The output is "Here" and then "Here2".

Comment: @DYZ Sorry, forgot to include that I have tried that too. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `aegsedrg` as such (or any other non-keyword string) in a standalone file is not a syntax error. It could be an identifier defined elsewhere in the program. `py_compile` does not execute the compiled file and cannot catch run-time errors (like `NameError`).

Try writing something syntactically incorrect in your file, such as the same string followed by a question mark:

```
py_compile.compile("test.py")
  File "test.py", line 1
    aegsedrg ?
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```